# MapFragment inside a fragment, app crash on reopening fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-nested-fragment

i have a mapfragment inside another fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
/>
</FrameLayout>
```

and im initializing map in oncreateview

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_fragment, null);
    try{
        events = new ArrayList<EventsModel>();

        try {               
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        double latitude = 24.875419;
        double longitude = 66.993293;
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(12).build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        loadEvents().execute();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }

    return view;
}
```

its working fine but when i press back button and reopen this fragment it crashes

```
04-19 21:18:21.803: E/AndroidRuntime(31612): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f050006, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
```

then i googled it and put it in ondestroy

```
Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();
```

the above problem is resolved bu now it gives me nullpointer on reopening the fragment that had mapfragment in it may be because i removed it with above code  but whats the solution now?

Comment: @WK try as per my answer and give me feedback on this.

Comment: but here you need to implement `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment` it's bacause you have to implement `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: the above problem is solved but now when i press back from MapFragment it crash (it should take me to the 1st fragment i came from)

04-19 21:54:58.581: E/AndroidRuntime(975): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 21:54:58.581: E/AndroidRuntime(975):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:651)

Comment: try to convert this MapFragment to SupportMapFragment

Comment: not working class cast exception :-/

Comment: but you have to change this every where

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be possible that your exception is caused by the nested fragment. And you might be used the [`getChildFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29) instead of `getFragmentManager()` method.

Comment: As @Fllo said. Use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` and also check if you fragment is null before creating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you have correctly checked the condition where map inflated is null or not while creating view for map fragment or while destroying.

put this one on onDestroy() method

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) 
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_location_sharing));

if(mapFragment != null) {
    FragmentManager fM = getFragmentManager();
    fM.beginTransaction().remove(mapFragment).commit();
```